# Given the alias, get the HostName from ssh config

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-config

I have an SSH config file like:

```
Host myAlias
  HostName the.actual.host.name.com
```

Is it possible to **resolve the hostname from the alias**, from the shell and without connecting to the host? I'm aiming for something like:

```
$ <something> myAlias
the.actual.host.name.com
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While it is possible to parse the ~/.ssh/config with a simple `awk` script, it might not work for arbitrary config file, which may have various blocks, etc. Consider instead using the 'ssh -G', which will dump the parameters of an ssh session, then extract the hostname attribute

```
ssh -G myAlias | awk '$1 == "hostname" { print $2 }'
```

Note that this has the advantage of supporting all ssh configuration sources (local config, command line, global config, environment variables, etc).

Just for completeness, quick and dirty `awk` solution

```
awk -v H="myAlias" '
tolower($1) == "host" { m=$2 == H }
tolower($1) == "hostname" && m{ print $2 }
' ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: That's great, I wasn't aware of `-G`. Thanks.

Comment: This is awesome. The `-G` option doesn't show in the help text, and isn't listed in the online man page, but is in my local man page. For those wondering: `-G Causes ssh to print its configuration after evaluating Host and Match blocks and exit.`